# Auto complete doesn't work at all for TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, autocomplete, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and just started a new TypeScript project. Auto completion doesn't work at all (braces, parenthesis, double quotes for strings ...)

Auto completion works fine with `.js` files and with `.html` files inside `script` tag but it doesn't work with `.ts` files.

Am I missing something??

P.S. I have Productivity Power Tools and Web Essentials extensions installed.

Comment: My canned response for this is to delete the .suo file in the solution, restart VS and reload the project and see if that helps. Its fixed it for me on a few occasions.